# SQL Server - How to delete some rows of columns without disrupting the rest of the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, procedure, xlsx

```
I have it
-- -- -- --
01 A1 B1 99
01 A1 B1 98
02 A2 B2 97
02 A2 B2 96

I need this
-- -- -- --
01 A1 B1 99
         98
02 A2 B2 97
         96
------------
```

I can not repeat the data that I will present in a excel, 
My result needs to be just so. 
In my actual table, the last column are responses of forms and the first columns (those that can not repeat) are customer data as (phone, name ...). 
The end result of this "query" will populate a "DataTable" and will be presented in a file "xlsx".

Thanks for sharing knowledge ^^

Comment: Your title should be in English, not Portuguese.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ??

Comment: Blank these values out as you loop through your DataTable and build the output for the xslx file - during that loop you can easily compare the current row to the previous row, and blank the first three columns out if they're the same. This isn't something you want to do in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL2012+

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1,LAG(Column1) OVER(ORDER BY Column1)),'')
 ,ISNULL(NULLIF(Column2,LAG(Column2) OVER(ORDER BY Column1,Column2)),'')
 ,ISNULL(NULLIF(Column3,LAG(Column3) OVER(ORDER BY Column1,Column2,Column3)),'')
 ,Column4
FROM #mytable
ORDER BY Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little messy, but you can do it in the database.  You basically make a subquery that gets the smallest value, and then join that to the regular table and blank out values that don't match.  I created your sample set like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable  (N1 VARCHAR(2), A VARCHAR(2), B VARCHAR(2), N2 VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
('01', 'A1', 'B1', '99'),
('01', 'A1', 'B1', '98'),
('02', 'A2', 'B2', '97'),
('02', 'A2', 'B2', '96')
```

And then was able to get the result like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN O.N2 = I.N2 THEN O.N1 ELSE '' END,
  CASE WHEN O.N2 = I.N2 THEN O.A ELSE '' END,
  CASE WHEN O.N2 = I.N2 THEN O.B ELSE '' END,
  O.N2
FROM
(SELECT MAX(N2) AS N2, N1, A, B FROM mytable GROUP BY N1, A, B) I
INNER JOIN mytable O
ON O.A = I.A AND O.B = I.B AND O.N1 = I.N1
ORDER BY O.N1 ASC
```

Comment: I wasn't saying you *can't* do it in the database. There are a lot of things you *can* do, but *can* <> *should*.

Answer (score 0):

we can use ROW_NUMBER to get the sequence and substitute '' for all rows where sequence is greater than 1

```
with CTE
AS
(   SELECT  ID, ColumnA, ColumnB, value,ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION by id order by id) as seq 
     FROM tableA
)
, CTE1
AS
(    
select id, ColumnA, ColumnB, value, seq from CTE where seq =1
UNION
SELECT id  ,'','', value , seq from CTE where seq >1

)
SELECT case when  seq >1 THEN NULL ELSE id END as id, columnA, columnB, value from CTE1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using a query.

You haven't provided DDL so I am going to asume your columns are called `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` respectively

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT a
       , b
       , c
       , d
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY d) As sequence
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT CASE WHEN sequence = 1 THEN a ELSE '' END As a
     , CASE WHEN sequence = 1 THEN b ELSE '' END As b
     , CASE WHEN sequence = 1 THEN c ELSE '' END As c
     , d
FROM   cte
ORDER
    BY a
     , b
     , c
     , d
```

The idea is to assign an incremental counter to each row, that restarts after each change of a + b + c.

We then use a conditional statement to show a value or not (basically only show on the first instance of each group)

Comment: I wasn't saying you *can't* do it in the database. There are a lot of things you *can* do, but *can* <> *should*.

Comment: I get what you're saying @AaronBertrand and normally I would be on the side of "do this in the presentation layer". However I have recently had the [dis]pleasure of working with Excel an awful lot as a reporting tool (using the term loosely) and based on this experience this path doesn't have that much resistance!

Answer (score 0):

The analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function is good for this. I've made up column names because you didn't supply any. To assign a row number by customer, use something like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Phone,
  Address,
  Response,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Phone, Address ORDER BY Response) AS CustRow
FROM myTable
```

That will assign row number within each customer. Try it yourself and I think it will make sense.

You can put it into a subquery or CTE from there and only show customer ID information like name, phone, and address when you're on the first row for each customer:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN CustRow = 1 THEN Name ELSE '' END AS Name,
  CASE WHEN CustRow = 1 THEN Phone ELSE '' END AS Phone,
  CASE WHEN CustRow = 1 THEN Address ELSE '' END AS Address,
  Response
FROM (
  SELECT
    Name,
    Phone,
    Address,
    Response,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Phone, Address ORDER BY Response) AS CustRow
   FROM myTable) custSubquery
ORDER BY Name, Phone, Address
```

The `custSubquery` on the second-to-last line is because SQL Server requires all subqueries to be aliased, even if the alias isn't used.

The most important thing is to determine how your last column will be ordered for display and to make sure that it's consistent in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as well as the final `ORDER BY`.

If you need more help, please supply table and column names, *and* specify how results are ordered within each customer.